# How to instantiate a class with base in the constructor?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I have the below class, I am trying to write unit test to test the UnhandledException method:

```
public class Workflow :WorkFlowManager
{
    public Workflow() : base(Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigurationFilesLocation"], confFileName))
    {
        this.RegistrationOutput = new Output();
    }

    public override async Task UnhandException(ModuleInterface module, Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}
```

I'm using xUnit and moq frameworks, and I'm confused about how to implement the constructor parameters.

Furthermore, I tried this Test:

```
[Fact]
public void UnhandledExceptionTest()
{
    var cls = new Workflow();
    var mock = new Mock<ModuleInterface>();
    var ser = new Mock<AServices>();
    var InteractionService = new Mock<InteractionService>();
    var iSharedLogService = new Mock<ISharedLogService>();
    Exception ex = new Exception();
    cls.UnhandException(mock.Object, ex);
}
```

But I'm having a System.ArgumentNullException because Path.Combine(String path1, String path2) in the constructor of `Workflow` can't be null.

Comment: What exactly is it that's null? Is it `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigurationFilesLocation"]`, `confFileName` or the result of `Path.Combine`? I'd recommend refactoring to introduce an abstraction over the application's configuration because statics make code inherently hard to test.

Comment: @Richiban I can't modify the code I'm only supposed to test it.  and the null exception is on  Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the exception so that we can see where it originates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a quick proof-of-concept to show that `Path.Combine` doesn't accept null arguments, so that means that either `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigurationFilesLocation"]` or `confFileName` is null. You will have to fix those values; unfortunately if you can't modify the class there's nothing else you can do.

Also, please tell your colleagues that this is not how you write testable code! Calling static methods in a base constructor makes it almost impossible to test nicely.